# Message Subscribers after recursive http-api calls

Tags: javascript, angular, recursion

I want to fetch a list of nodes to create an array of said node objects in order to display an hierarchy. The based data/structure looks like this:

```
ROOT (ID=1)
|--NODE (ID=2)
|  └--NODE (ID=4)
|     └--NODE (ID=11)
└--NODE (ID=3)
   |--NODE (ID=5)
   |--NODE (ID=6)
   |--NODE (ID=7)
   └--NODE (ID=8)
      |--NODE (ID=9)
      └--NODE (ID=10)
```

You have a Root Node, with child nodes which also contain childs. Inclucing the ROOT node, there are 3 stages in the tree. I created an REST-API which returns the children inside the given node. I also tried to model this hierarchy inside my REST structure, so the calls look like this:

```
TYPE        PATH                      RESULT CHILD IDs
GET         /1/nodes                  2, 3
GET         /1/nodes/2/nodes          4
GET         /1/nodes/3/nodes          5, 6, 7, 8
GET         /1/nodes/3/nodes/8/nodes  9, 10
```

In order to build a tree I tried to use a recursive pattern, something like this:

```
    this.subject.next(this.getNodes('/1/nodes'); /*root-uri*/

    getNodes(uri) {
      const nodeList: Node[] = [];
      http.get(path).subscribe(data => {
        for(const obj of data.json()) {
            let node = new Node();
            //map data to Node e.g node.is = data.id

            //get the children with the nested call
            node.children = getNodes(uri + '/' + node.id + '/nodes'); 
            nodeList.push(node);
        }
    }
    return nodeList;
}
```

So my question is:
**How to create an array of node objects from recursive http calls and send an message to subscribers so that the subscriber only receives the complete array of nodes in the correct structure**

---

**EDIT**

This is how the Node Model looks like

```
export class Node {
  uuid: string;
  label: string;
  parentID: string;
  version: number;
  addableFlag: boolean;
  sectionFlag: boolean;
  children: Node[];
}
```

Comment: You are returning nodeList in a synchronous fashion, this will not work.

Comment: @Salketer Can you show me an example how to do it the proper way?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set the `this.subject` value with in the `subscribe()` scope. So that way it has a complete list in correct structure before setting the values.

```js
this.getChildren('/1/nodes'); /*root-uri*/

getNodes(uri) {
    const nodeList: Node[] = [];
    http.get(path).subscribe(data => {
        for (const obj of data.json()) {
          let node = new Node();
          //map data to Node e.g node.is = data.id

          //get the children with the nested call
          node.children = getNodes(uri + '/' + node.id + '/nodes');
          nodeList.push(node);
        }
        this.subject.next(nodeList); /*root-uri*/
    }
      // Return would send empty data as this line get executed before data arrives
      // return nodeList;
}
```

That will work as it sets the value of the `subject` when it has data.

Comment: How do I add the child nodes to the children array? The line `node.children = getNodes(uri)` deosn´t work since node.children is accepting an Node array but the method doesn´t return anything.