# Angular2 recursive http calls

Tags: angular, recursion, iframe, observable

I have a http service in angular which returns a txt/html, I parse the response to find any iframe tags and for each iframe I call the same service to get the inner html which in itself can also have iframe tags and so on.
This recursive call is done until there is no more iframes to fetch. 
What I want to do is to process & update the response each time (overwrite the src of the iframe).

```
//service
getHtmlFile(file: string) {
  const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders('X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}),
    //observe: 'response' as 'response',
    responseType: 'text' as 'text'
  };

  return this.http.get(url, httpOptions); //set headers
}

//Not working
getHtml(file: string) {
this.httpService.getHtmlFile(file)
  .subscribe(res => {
    const iframes = getIframes(res); //get list of iframes from res.
    //loop through the list and recursively get html files
    for (let i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
       const src = extractSrc(iframes[i]);//extract the src attribute
       this.getHtml(src);//recursive call
       res = res.replace(iframes[i], newvalue); //want to update res here?
    }
    return res;
  });
}
```

I can do this for each request but can't figure out how to accumulate the changes in the recursive call so that the parent html res will have the changes from its childs. The subscriber would only get the final result which has all the changes applied. Not sure how this works with observable response from the service?

Not sure if this is clear, but in short, its a tree like structure where each node value (from Observable) should be injected/replaced in its parent value (also from Observable)!

This is Angular 5.

Came across angular *expand* option but not sure how to maintain the tree structure with it. This is a similar question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45921536/message-subscribers-after-recursive-http-api-calls)

//Edit

Sorry if what I'm trying to achieve is not clear. Here is example of input files and the desired output result. Hope this makes sense now.

```
//index.html
<html>
<body>
  <!-- iframes -->
  <iframe src="file1.html"></iframe>
  <iframe src="file2.html"></iframe>
</body>
</html>

//file1.html
<html>
<body>
  <!-- iframes -->
  <iframe src="file1_1.html"></iframe>
</body>
</html>

//file2.html
<html>
<body>
  <!-- body with no iframes -->
</body>
</html>

//file1_1.html
<html>
<body>
  <!-- body with no iframes -->
</body>
</html>
```

output should be top level index.html with iframe src as blobs, as below.
The key here is that file1/file2 should also have its iframes src set as blob before its set in index frames as blob, and so on.

```
<html>
<body>
  <!-- iframes -->
  <iframe src="blob(file1)"></iframe>
  <iframe src="blob(file2)"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This wont solve your full problem, but part of your problem is that you need to subscribe to your service. Otherwise the function will terminate before you are done processing.

```
getHtml = (file: string): Observable<any>{
  return new Observable<any>(observer => {
    this.httpService.getHtmlFile(file)
      .subscribe(res => {

        const iframes = getIframes(res);

        for (let i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
          const index = i; // not sure if you need this, but you might lose scope in your loop
          const src = extractSrc(iframes[i]);
          this.getHtml(src).subscribe(newRes => {
            res = res.replace(iframes[inex], newRes);
          });
        }

        observer.next(res);
        observer.complete();
      });
  });
}
```

**edit** this solution utilizes the rxjs Observable

Answer (score 0):

I think that´s working exactly how you coded. The key here is, in my opinion, you´re returning the value, but no one is expecting it. What I would do is store the final value into a variable instead returning it.

In order to isolate the behaviour into the service, I also use concatMap. Now, I think this is what you want:

```
//service
getHtmlFile(file: string) {
  const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders(
    {
      'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    }),
    //observe: 'response' as 'response',
    responseType: 'text' as 'text'
  };

  //set headers
  return this.http.get(url, httpOptions).pipe(
    concatMap( (res) => {
        //get list of iframes from res.
        const iframes = getIframes(res);

        //loop through the list and recursively get html files
        for (let i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
           //extract the src attribute
           const src = extractSrc(iframes[i]);

           //recursive call
           this.getHtml(src);

           //want to update res here?
           res = res.replace(iframes[i], newvalue);
        }

        return res;
   }));
}

//not working
getHtml(file: string) {
  this.httpService.getHtmlFile(file)
    .subscribe( res => {
       this.variableInComponent = res;
    });
}
```

This way, you can isolate the loop and recursive call into the first function, and make it private. Any time you call getHtml, before subscribe execute, the concatMap block will do his thing and return the value to subscribe.

In any case, I didn´t understand all you want to achieve, but I think there´s something wrong with the recursive call in this observable pattern...